# Zend soap server comments

Tags: soap, zend-soap

To generate wsdl I'm using Zend Soap server. This auto addind comments like

```
<!--You may enter the following 2 items in any order-->
```

how to avoid this comments ?

Comment: Which version of Zend Soap server/Zend Framework are you using?

Comment: @JamesG I'm using  zendframework/zend-soap2.2.5

Comment: I have checked the ZF2 code and I can't find anything in there that looks like it is adding those comments. I also wrote a basic test using the AutoDiscover() class to generate the WSDL and it did not include any comments like that. You will need to post the code that is using Zend Framework to generate the WSDL in order to go any further.